# Android Trigger a specific path

Tags: android, triggers, media, sd-card

I want to trigger the media, but not the whole media (as it takes too much time on some devices), what i want to trigger is **/mnt/sdcard/my_folder** . I'm triggering my media using

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

How can i trigger a specific folder? Thanks!

Comment: What does "trigger the media" mean? Why are you broadcasting an `Intent` that you should not be?

Comment: Actually, that intent works for photo picker from the gallery. And here trigger means to refresh or update the media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to "refresh or update the media" is to use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()`, not to send a broadcast that is supposed to be sent by the operating system.

Comment: @Numair: As I wrote, use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html